# Probability of obtaining a sequence

Tags: probability

We have $A,C,T,G$ as the deoxyribonucleic acid basis. What is the probabiltiy that, in a sequence of 9 digits, we get

$$AAATCGAGT$$

?

Now, i am not sure about it, but it seems to me that the probability will be $(1/4)^9$, just like any other sequence, but i am really skeptical about that. The point is that this sequence is unique, so over the $4^9$ possible, only one is the one we want.

Comment: There isn't enough information to answer this.  That answer would be correct if each compound was equally likely to be present in each slot, independent of what's in all the other slots, but you didn't specify anything remotely like that.   Applying general probabilistic principals to real world problems without any thought about potential complications is very unlikely to yield sensible results.

Comment: If $A$, $C$, $T$ and $G$ have the same probability, it is correct. But you should consider lulu's comment.

Comment: In line with the comment of @lulu, if you intend that this is a random sequence of amino acids taken from a randomly chosen portion of the general *human genome*, I suggest that you discuss the problem with a **Bioinformatics Professor**.

Answer (score 1):

If the probability of $A$, $G$, $T$ and $C$ are the same, your answer is correct.

Otherwise, the probability is
$$p(A)^4p(T)^2p(G)^2p(C)\frac{9!}{4!2!2!1!}$$

You should prove, as an exercise, that in the first case, both answers match!